# My Spring Boot app is not able to deploy, it gets a continuous reference error, it seems the problem is my repository is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, debugging

I'm new to using spring boot and I'm trying to create my first Spring Boot application. I've been looking through tutorials and mixing stuff up that seemed simple enough to implement for a Spring Boot beginner.

I've looked online at it seems the only time this happens is if someone assigns a service using the repository instead of auto wiring it I did not do such a thing.

My program ends up null causing the following stack:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userAuthentificationServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bCryptPasswordEncoder'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:355) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:227) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
```

my repository

```
import com.example.realtyKing.Model.User;
import com.example.realtyKing.Model.UserAuthentification;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserAuthentificationRepository extends 
JpaRepository<UserAuthentification, 
Long> {

public UserAuthentification findByUser(User User);
public UserAuthentification findByAuthUserName(String username);

}
```

the implementation class

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import com.example.realtyKing.Model.Role;
import com.example.realtyKing.Model.UserAuthentification;
import com.example.realtyKing.Repositories.UserAuthentificationRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


@Service
public class UserAuthentificationDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserAuthentificationRepository userAuthetificationRepository;

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    UserAuthentification userAuthetification=userAuthetificationRepository.findByAuthUserName(username);

    Set < GrantedAuthority > grantedAuthorities = new HashSet < > ();
    for (Role role: userAuthetification.getRoles()) {
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
    }

    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(userAuthetification.getAuthUserName(), userAuthetification.getAuthPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
}
}
```

the security config class

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;




 import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication
.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import 
org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.
configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration
.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;


@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder()
{
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/userAuthentificationForm").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return authenticationManager();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
{
    
auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

ps the imports for the last one are alined properly it was hard to fit those long imports through the text on this small screen.

Comment: you can Autowire the BCryptPasswordEncoder into the UserAuthentificationDetailsServiceImpl instead

Answer (score 2):

You're showing us the wrong code, but from the error message, it seems you have another class called `UserAuthentificationServiceImpl` (not the same as `UserAuthentificationDetailsServiceImpl`).

The problem is that this class is autowired in `WebSecurityConfig`, but also needs your `BCryptPasswordEncoder` bean from `WebSecurityConfig`. So basically you have a cyclic dependency:

1. **`UserAuthentificationServiceImpl`** depends on `BCryptPasswordEncoder` (due to `@Autowired`)
2. `BCryptPasswordEncoder` depends on `WebSecurityConfig`  (due to bean being in that class)
3. `WebSecurityConfig` depends on **`UserAuthentificationServiceImpl`** (due to `@Autowired`)

To fix this, you could move the `BCryptPasswordEncoder` our of your `WebSecurityConfig`. For example, by creating a new class:

```java
@Configuration
public class PasswordSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

If you do this, you break the cyclic dependency, because then `BcryptPasswordEncoder` no longer depends on `WebSecurityConfig`.

Answer (score 0):

Does you model `UserAuthentification` have annotation `@Component`. Also just cross check if all the properties in the Model classes have getters and setters. I have missed this one time and my response didn't contain that properties which didn't have getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your @Bean inside your security config class not public.

Make this:

```
@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder()
{
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

To this:

```
@Bean
BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder()
{
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```